# Best way to upgrade project from Vue2 to Vue3

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2, vuejs3

I would like to upgrade my project to `vue3`

This is a `symfony` application using vue as independent components on the front side

I have never done a major upgrade before and not too sure what the best procedure would be ?

- Should I uninstall `vue2` then install `vue3` ?
- should I just install `vue3` ?
- should I just modify my `package.json` directly ?

  ```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "elm-pep": "^1.0.6",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "svg-url-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-date-pick": "^1.4.1",
    "vue-material-design-icons": "^4.9.0",
    "vue2-editor": "^2.10.2",
    "vuelayers": "^0.12.0-dev.9"
  }
  ```

Comment: [Migration from Vue 2](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/introduction.html) is your best resource at this point, keep in mind there isn't  a step by step guide yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [`migration guide`](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/introduction.html#breaking-changes)

> **INFO**
> We are still working on a dedicated Migration Build of Vue 3 with Vue 2 compatible behavior and runtime warnings of incompatible usage. If you are planning to migrate a non-trivial Vue 2 app, we strongly recommend waiting for the Migration Build for a smoother experience.

Now it's very hard to migrate manually a large application from Vue 2 because the most libraries have not supported Vue 3 yet like `vuelayers`. The migration should take in consideration the upgrade of the libraries/components.

Comment: vue3 alternative for vuelayers is vue3-openlayers for documentation https://vue3openlayers.netlify.app/

Comment: link doesn't work try https://vueframework.com/guide/migration/introduction.html#breaking-changes